# Angular 2 Base Class Output EventEmitter doesn't get raised or handled

Tags: event-handling, angular, derived-class, base-class, eventemitter

Very simple base class `Closer`

```
import {EventEmitter, Output} from 'angular2/core';

export class Closer {
  @Output() closed: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {}

  close() {
    this.closed.emit({});
  }
}
```

If I `extends Closer` another class and then mark it up with

```
<derived-class (closed)="closeHandler()"></derived-class>
```

`closeHandler()` will never get called.  I can see `Closer.close()` getting called but the emit doesn't get propagated by the derived class or handled by the class whose template contains the derived class and event binding.

If I simply move the `@Output` to the derived class it works. But it would seem that Angular2 should be putting that on derived classes.  The ability to fully define a set of behavior and inherit it would be nice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem this morning and just figured out how to do it.  All you have to do is add **outputs: ['closed']** to the components section of the derived class that is extending Closer and you have to remove **@Output()** from the closed declaration inside the Closer class

Here is a quick demo based on your example:

**Derived Class:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'derived-class',
  outputs: ['closed']
})
export class DerivedClass extends Closer {}
```

**Closer Class:**

```
import {EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';

export class Closer {
  closed: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {}

  close() {
    this.closed.emit({});
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Please note if you're using tslint you can disable the linter error with `// tslint:disable-next-line:use-output-property-decorator`

Comment: I have an inherited directive which uses `EventEmitter` and for some reason this approach does not work there either..